# Method to find string in text file, then add in string to text file if string is not found else reject entry

Tags: java, text, methods

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
if (args.length == 1)
{
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("fruit.txt"));
    int linecount = 0;
    String line;
    //run thur the txt file to check if input exist
    while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null)
    {
        linecount++;
        int indexfound = line.indexOf(args[0]);
        if (indexfound > -1) {
            System.out.println("fruit exist on line " + linecount);
            System.out.println("add another fruit");    
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("fruit.txt", true));
            String fruit = "";
            fruit = args[0];
            bw.write("\r\n" + fruit);
            System.out.println(fruit+ "added"); 
        }
    }
    f.close();
    bw.close();
}
```

I want to have the program to search in a text file fruit.txt
check if a fruit already exist in it.

if fruit exist then prompt user to input another 1

else 
add in to the nextline of the text file

This is what I got so far.
but I am not sure why it isnt what I wanted.

in my text file it started with 3 fruit

```
apple
orange
pear
```

after i add in berry

```
apple
orange
pear
berry
berry
```

after i add in melon

```
apple
orange
pear
berry
berry
melon
melon
melon
melon
```

Comment: please format your code properly before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just checking for the fruit in the first line, and if it is not found, you are continuing to add it.

You need to read your file completely first, one for checking each line, that it contains your fruit or not, and then if it does not contain, just dump that fruit in it. And if it contains, reject it.

So, in your while, you need to move that else part outside. And rather than doing `System.exit()` when fruit is found, you can set a boolean variable to true, and then later on, based on the value of boolean variable, you can decide whether to add the fruit or not.

```
boolean found = false;
while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null) {

    linecount++;
    int indexfound = line.indexOf(args[0]);
    if (indexfound > -1) {
        System.out.println("fruit exist on line " + linecount);
        System.out.println("add another fruit");   
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!found) {

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("fruit.txt", true));
    String fruit = "";
    fruit = args[0];

    bw.write("\r\n" + fruit);
    System.out.println(fruit+ "added"); 

    bw.close();  // You need to close it here only. 
}

bf.close();
```

Comment: @newbieprogrammer. Yup. Try the above code. Notice that I'm reading every line in the while loop, and if a single line contains the fruit, I set the boolean variable to true, and break out of loop.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer. Edited the code.. It should be `if(!found)`. check that.

Comment: I was looking for the flag indicator and i see now in the answer

Comment: @KaipaMSarma. Hmm. Yup flag indicator is always needed in such cases. :)

Comment: @Rohit Jain thanks much
break; is better than using system exit