# Avoid repetition when writing strings to text file line by line

Tags: java, android, regex, text

I use the following code to write strings to my simple text file:

**EDITED:**

```
private String fileLocation="/mnt/sdcard/out.txt";

public void saveHisToFile()
{
    if (prefs.getBoolean("saveHis", true) && mWordHis != null && mWordHis.size() >= 1)
    {
        StringBuilder sbHis = new StringBuilder();          
        Set<String> wordSet= new HashSet<String>(mWordHis);
        for (String item : wordSet)
        {
            sbHis.append(item);
            sbHis.append("\n");
        }

        String strHis = sbHis.substring(0, sbHis.length()-1);  
        try {
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
                     fileLocation), true));
             bw.write(strHis);
             bw.newLine();
             bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

The strings are successfully written to the text file, but weirdly, some strings are overwritten, such as:

```
apple
orange
grapes
grapes
grapes
apple 
kiwi
```

My question is:

1. how can I stop a string being written more than once?
2. how can I stop writing a string (a line) to the file if it has already existed in the file?

I have consulted [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13044285/998032) but failed to apply it to my case. Can you please give a little help? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It sounds like `mWordHis` (whatever that's meant to mean) contains the same word multiple times... or you're running this code multiple times.

Comment: Oh yes, that the case because it's kind of history word. I am trying test all your suggestions and will get back to you guys very soon. Many thanks.

Comment: Ok, after re-reading your question, is it correct that this history file can persist between executions of your program? if thats the case, then you may need to read all the words from this file into a Set, and then compare against that set before you write to it.

Comment: I have tried all the suggestions given by you guys, which are all very helpful to me. But it seems that we are misled. My case is to write an items (words) to a text file line by line, and if a particular item already exists, it must not be written again. So I think, the matter is to check the text file for any duplicates.

Comment: No, actually all 3 solutions provided solve your problem. You just implemented the proposed solution incorrectly. Your mistake is either of the following three:

A) Your text file already has items: then you need to read the text file first and populate the HashSet with the existing words.

B) You didn't declare the HashSet globally and instead recreate a HashSet on each call of your save function, in this case you need to move the HashSet out of your function and make it global and a Singleton.

C) You have concurrent access to your HashSet. Then you have to make access to it synchronized.

Comment: @noamik: You are a star! Absolutely right in defining my mistake. It is A that causes my problem, i.e., my text file has items. Let's say I want to write XYZ to my text file but ZYZ has already existed in the text file. Currently, ZYZ is always inserted into the file regardless of its presence in the text file.

Comment: See my second solution on how to tackle issue A ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete example on how to solve your problem:

```
      import java.io.BufferedReader;
      import java.io.BufferedWriter;
      import java.io.File;
      import java.io.FileReader;
      import java.io.FileWriter;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.util.HashSet;

      public class HisSaver {
        private HashSet<String> uniqueTester = new HashSet<String>();

        private String fileLocation="/mnt/sdcard/out.txt";

        private static HisSaver instance = null;


        private HisSaver() {
            readWordsFromFile();
        }

        public static HisSaver getInstance() {
            if(instance == null)
                instance = new HisSaver();
            return instance;
        }

        public void saveWord(String word) {
            if(!uniqueTester.contains(word)) {
                uniqueTester.add(word);
                writeWordToFile(word);
            }
        }

        private void writeWordToFile(String word) {
          try {
               BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
                       fileLocation), true));
               bw.write(word);
               bw.newLine();
               bw.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {

          }
        }

        private void readWordsFromFile() {
          try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                fileLocation)));
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(!uniqueTester.contains(line)) {
                    uniqueTester.add(line);
                }
            }
          } catch (IOException e) {

          }
        }
      }
```

Now to use this, you simply do the following in your code:

```
    HisSaver hs = HisSaver.getInstance();
    hs.saveWord("newWord");
```

This will insert the "newWord" if and only if it is not already in your file, provided that no other function in your code accesses this file. Please note: this solution is NOT thread safe!!!

Edit: Explanation of what the code does:
We create a class HisSaver which is a singleton. This is realized by making it's constructor private and providing a static method getInstance() which returns an initialized HisSaver. This HisSaver will already contain all preexisting words in your file and thus only append new words to it. Calling the getInstance() method from another class will give you a handle for this singleton and allow you to call saveWord without having to worry whether you have the right object in your hands, since only one instance of it can ever be instantiated.

Comment: Dear noamik: I'm so grateful for your help. I have been testing your new method and so far it has been working well, i.e., it saves items to the text file and if an item is already present in the file, it does not write that item to the file. I am accepting your method as an answer to my question. Thank you so much. (But if the problem persists or if I have a new question, how can I again "bother" you?)

Comment: Sure, you can try. Just be aware that my answer might take some time if I do not happen to be reading stackoverflow when you're asking :-D
It might be faster to just open a new question if you have a new one, since there are many more eyes on them compared to a comment here.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public void saveHisToFile(Set<String> existingWords)
{
    if (prefs.getBoolean("saveHis", true) && mWordHis != null && mWordHis.size() >= 1)
    {
        StringBuilder sbHis = new StringBuilder();
        for (String item : mWordHis)
        {
            if (!existingWords.contains(item)) {
                sbHis.append(item);
                sbHis.append("\n");
            }
        }

        String strHis = sbHis.substring(0, sbHis.length()-1);
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
                    fileLocation), true));
            bw.write(strHis);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @NiamhDoyle you actually are appending to the output file every time you execute the program, is this your intention Niamh? Have you tried removing the output file and rerun it.

Comment: Well, actually my output file a history file so I want to keep it. Every time when a word is chosen, it will be put into this file.

Comment: @NiamhDoyle Ok, well then you need to read the words from the history file prior to executing `saveHisToFile()`, and make the existing words available somehow, for example as a parameter `Set<String> existingWords`. (see my edit)

Answer (score 2):

I guess `mWordHis` is a `List`, which can contain duplicate entries.
You can first convert it to a `Set` (which doesn't allow duplicates) and print only the words in the `Set`.

```
    Set<String> wordSet= new HashSet<>(mWordHis);

    for (String item : wordSet)
    {
        sbHis.append(item);
        sbHis.append("\n");
    }
```

As @fge commented, `LinkedHashSet` may also be used if insertion order matters.

If you need to run the same code several times with the same file, you must either save in memory all the records you've already wrote to the file, or read the file and get all data before writing to it.

Edit:

I can only think about trimming the words as some may contain unneeded spaces:

```
    Set<String> wordSet= new HashSet<>();
    for (String item : mWordHis){
        wordSet.add(item.trim());
    }
```

Comment: Maybe use a `LinkedHashSet` if insertion order matters?

Comment: @Niamh Doyle do you run this code several times with the same file?

Comment: @NiamhDoyle it should work. There is something you do not tell in your question.

Comment: @fge@whoAmI: Hi all, please have a look at my edited code, which is the whole thing. I have no idea why it does not work despite your proper suggestions.

Comment: I take it you actually need to _retain_ the set between the different save operations. Create a wrapping class.

Answer (score 1):

You could add all the strings into a HashMap and check for each new String if it is are already in there.

Example:

```
    HashMap<String,String> test = new HashMap<String,String>();
    if(!test.containsKey(item)) {
      test.put(item,"");
      // your processing: example
      System.out.println(item);
    } else {
      // Your processing of duplicates, example:
      System.out.println("Found duplicate of: " + item);
    }
```

Edit: or use a HashSet as shown by the other solutions ...

```
    HashSet<String> test = new HashSet<String>();
    if(!test.contains(item)) {
      test.add(item);
      // your processing: example
      System.out.println(item);
    } else {
      // Your processing of duplicates, example:
      System.out.println("Found duplicate of: " + item);
    }
```

Edit2:

```
    private String fileLocation="/mnt/sdcard/out.txt";

    public void saveHisToFile()
    {
        if (prefs.getBoolean("saveHis", true) && mWordHis != null && mWordHis.size() >= 1)
        {
            StringBuilder sbHis = new StringBuilder();  
            HashSet<String> test = new HashSet<String>();

            Set<String> wordSet= new HashSet<String>(mWordHis);
            for (String item : wordSet)
            {
                if(!test.contains(item)) {
                    test.add(item);
                    // your processing: example
                    sbHis.append(item+System.lineSeparator());
                } else {
                    // Your processing of duplicates, example:
                    //System.out.println("Found duplicate of: " + item);
                }
            }

            String strHis = sbHis.toString();  
            try {
                 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
                         fileLocation), true));
                 bw.write(strHis);
                 bw.newLine();
                 bw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can just do `if (!test.add(item)) sout("duplicate");`. Set.add actually returns a boolean.

Comment: Sure, one can always optimize, but I'll let the code as is for easier understanding of what happens. He might use you optimization once he understood why the code does what he wants it to do :-D

Comment: @noamik: Can you please be more specific regarding my edited code? I have tried the HashSet way but there's no luck.

Comment: @NiamhDoyle I updated my example to show you how the solution is meant to be applied. Please be aware that this is just for instruction and not beautiful code. The code can be optimized like melwil proposed. But since you had trouble understanding the suggestions, I preferred to keep the simplified version.

Comment: Btw.: this edit2 is just to show you how my proposal is meant to work. The actual code is non-sense, since the iterator on wordSet should already be unique on each element. So this is just meant for your understanding how you can use the HashSet to solve your uniqueness-problem. Since wordSet should be unique in each of his elements in the first place, you wouldn't need to filter it. If you still get duplicates, you have other issues in your code or in your strings (for example the strings could look the same, but have different characters to build them) ...

Comment: If you want to be sure to have the same strings and no character issues, convert them to byte[] and compare those: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Many thanks for your help. In fact, I'm teaching myself and my Java understanding is quite limited, so your proposal is an extremely good source. Anyway, `HashSet<String> test = new HashSet<String>;` always causes `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's my fault. It should be
        `HashSet<String> test = new HashSet<String>();`